# XSLT 2.0 processor for Linux CLI / contains() function in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, linux, xslt

It's not 100% a programming question, but I hope it's fits here.

Do you know any lightweight XSLT 2.0 processor for Linux (cli)?

xsltproc is for XSLT ver. 1.0 only.

I found only saxon processor, but this one requires Java (which I really don't want to install).

**Alternatively, can you recommend me an XSLT v1 solution for contains() function?**

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:for-each select="offer[contains(lower-case(name),'find this one')]">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Currently, your question is asking for a tool recommendation - this kind of question is off-topic on SO and will likely be closed eventually. Perhaps you could reword the question to ask how your XSLT 2.0 code could be translated to work with XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of such a processor, but it's relatively straightforward to re-code that stylesheet to be 1.0 compatible by using the `translate` function to replace the `lower-case` one, and it will then work with `xsltproc`.

If you want to select *all* `offer` elements that match the condition (and there might be more than one of them) then you need to wrap a single root-level element around them all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <offers>
          <xsl:copy-of select="//offer[contains(
             translate(name, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
             'find this one')]" />
       </offers>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

If you know there will only ever be *one* matching offer then you don't necessarily need the wrapper element.

Comment: Great answer, If we don't find a tool I accept your answer. BTW I started using your solution, because xsltproc for v1 is already installed and your answer is working great.